# PHP in_array doesnt work right?

Tags: php

So I am trying to see if a set of numbers is in an array.

```
array(3) { 
     [0]=> array(2) { 
        ["account_ID"]=> string(10) "1781890863" 
        [0]=> string(10) "1781890863" 
      } 
     [1]=> array(2) { 
        ["account_ID"]=> string(10) "2093832999" 
        [0]=> string(10) "2093832999" 
      } 
     [2]=> array(2) { 
        ["account_ID"]=> string(10) "2147483647" 
        [0]=> string(10) "2147483647" } 
      }
```

I have the array and the values are all there and everything is just dandy. But when I compare using in_array it returns false. I don't quite know why.

```
class DB(){

    public function getAllID(){
        $result_row = $this->accessDB( 'SELECT account_ID FROM users;');
        return $result_row; 
    }
}
```

That is the function that I am using to access the database and return the array and then

```
$app = new DB();
if(isset($_GET['user'])){
    if(in_array($_GET['user'],$app->getAllID())){
        include('account.php');
        echo 'Account DOES exist';
    } else {
        var_dump($app->getAllID());
        echo '<br/>'.$_GET['user'].' does NOT exist.';
    } 
}
```

Does anyone see why my code here won't work maybe I am just accessing the DB wrong?

Comment: what does the var_dump($app->getAllID()); look like?

Comment: return $result_row; will return an associative array so yes the way you are trying will not work

Comment: The `var_dum($app->getAllID());` Is above.

Comment: is the value of $_GET['user'] 0, 1, or 2?

Comment: The value of $_GET['user'] should be one of the items of the array. When It is set to one of the items it returns false, when it it set to a number other than that in the array it returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method returns array of assoc array, instead of array of int/string (on which your check is working).

Easiest solution - pull `account_ID` one level up.

```
public function getAllID(){
    $result_row = $this->accessDB( 'SELECT account_ID FROM users;');
    return array_map(function($entry) { return $entry['account_ID']; }, $result_row); 
}
```

Better solution - validate with DB query:

```
// must escape $userId before doing query or you are vulnerable to SQL injection

$this->accessDB("SELECT count(account_ID) FROM users WHERE account_ID = {$userId} LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Using array_map is much cleaner than the answer I posted. I also like that you mentioned validating the specific user rather than querying for all user ids

Comment: If I were to validate with a DB query would I still return the `array_map` or would I return `$result_row` ?

Comment: As query returns only one field in one row (the `count`) I would convert that one value to `bool`. Using var format you gave in question your count value, `return (1 == $result_row[0][0]);` should work for `isUserFound($userId)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through `$app->getAllID()` because if the `$_GET['user']` is there it will be in `$app->getAllID()[0]`, `$app->getAllID()[1]` etc..

Really, you should do this check for `$_GET['user']` in the query with a WHERE clause and return true if it exists and false if not.  Why query and return all `account_ID`s just to check if one exists?

Answer (score 0):

Your function pulling the query results is returning a multi-deminsional array. You can either loop through the array to determine if `$_GET['user']` is in each array within or change your function that is pulling the user ids.

In your function loop through your query results and build your array:

```
$user_ids = array();
foreach ($result_row as $record) {
    $user_ids[] = $record['account_ID'];
}
return $user_ids;
```

This will create an array of user ids. Then you can use `in_array()` to determine if the user id exists.